# Mails Content - Center or left aligment

Tags: email, content, responsive, newsletter

I'm designing transactional mails to send notifications to clients. Some of my colleagues say the content should be left aligned, but I personally think in the cases where there is little content and it comes with with a CTA button, it should be centered.

How could we justify the use of center align text in this situation? Do you know best practices?

Mail is responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For transactional emails, it's better to give the information front and center so that the user can easily get the information he's looking for. So, it will work for little content with a direct CTA. However,if you even have a paragraph of content, don't center align it. [It has readability issues.](http://uxmovement.com/content/why-you-should-never-center-align-paragraph-text/)

This particular **[guide to transactional emails](http://blog.getvero.com/guides/the-complete-guide-to-transactional-email/)** can help you with identifying the positions of various elements in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Long paragraphs should always be left-aligned, so as to avoid readibility issues. Centered content should be used for everything else, images, call-to-action, slogans, etc.

You should also make sure the paragraph's font has the right size, as having less than 5 words per line will trigger readibility issues too, as well as more than 10.